# For + slideToggle no Jquery não funciona

Tags: jquery, html, css

Alguém pode explicar porque meu código não funciona? Eu não sei exatamente quantas `divs` irão gerar, mas o máximo são 25.

Então queria que a cada botão de click, abrisse especificamente a `div` "cola" ligada a ele.

No meu pensamento, coloquei um `for` que vai percorrendo, dando nome a classe --- se `i` for 2 o `click_a2` vai abrir o `cola2` e assim por diante.

O jQuery e o HTML:

```js
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            $('.click_a'+i).click(function () {
                    $('.cola'+i).slideToggle();
            });
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click_a1"> Detalhes </button>
        <div class="cola1" style="display:none" >
        hey!
        </div>
```

Obs: Entenda-se que colocarei uma variável (no lugar do `1`) que irá somar tudo que esse código rodar.

https://jsfiddle.net/rgLjpb7s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O teu código não funciona porque esse `i` [já não tem o valor que queres que tenha quando o click fôr chamado](https://jsfiddle.net/rgLjpb7s/2/).

Se criares um escopo novo isso já funciona, assim o valor da variável fica guardado dentro desse escopo:

```
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        $('.click_a' + i).click(function () {
            $('.cola' + i).slideToggle();
        });
    })(i)
};
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rgLjpb7s/1/

Podes também fazer assim uma vez que estás a usar jQuery:

```
$('[class^=click_a').each(function (i) {
    (function () {
        var nr = i + 1;
        var cola = $('.cola' + nr);
        $(this).click(function () {
            cola.slideToggle();
        });
    })();
});
```

tem 2 vantagens: funciona para *n* numero de `.click_a`, outro é que coloca o elemento que faz slide em cache melhorando um pouco a performance.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rgLjpb7s/3/

Comment: Muito obrigado, terei que estudar um pouco mais para conseguir entender porque isso acontece. Pensei que a variável continuaria o mesmo valor, uma vez que não sai do for. Em todo caso, obrigado!